# What is the German word of this small boat that you usually rent for two people?

Tags: single-word-request

What is the German word of this small boat that you usually rent for two people?

[image: Small boat that you can rent usually for two person]

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. Can you please [edit] your question to specify: 1) Do you know a word for these boats in any other language? 2) If yes, what did a dictionary give you as an answer and why does it not satisfy you? 3) What features of these boats shall the requested word capture: the swan form, the number of seats, the method of propulsion, the intended usage, …?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft . Hello. I simply did not know the name in german for this kind of boat. I saw them in Germany but did not know the name of them. Please, feel free to change the question accordingly. Danke.

Comment: Go to the [Leo English-German dictionary](http://dict.leo.org/german-english/pedal%20boat) and type in PEDAL BOAT.

Comment: @sparskter: What Wrzlprmpft was trying to tell you that there are different kinds of these boats and the name depends upon which kind they are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even if swan-shaped, I can't imagine of any other word than

> Tretboot

While this would also apply to other small and somewhat bigger boats (I recall having seen ones with 4 seats and possibly a small area to lay down after taking a swim), any construction like *Schwanentretboot* would be understood, but is unlikely to be used broadly.

Comment: Related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GdACuh-nbrw

Comment: Unless it's another kind of "small boat that you usually rent for two people", such as a *Ruderboot* or a *Motorboot* (yes, you can sometimes rent veeery slow versions of the latter, e.g. at Austria's Hallstätter See).